# Make text appear above background in HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone this is my first webpage i've made and i'm trying to display a gif as backrgound and make text appear above that.. Everything works fine except i can't seem to display the text above the gif background.. As you can see in the source code i have one heading and three paragraphs, Anyone knows how to fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i91751/icons8/windows-8/Systems-Linux.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title>FirstWebpage</title>

    <style>
body{ /* Will use a gif as background */
 background-image: url('http://images.eurogamer.net/2015/articles/1/8/7/1/5/3/2/san-francisco-subway-system-hacked-passengers-get-free-rides-148033947612.gif');
 background-position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
    }


    </style>
    <audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="seffelinie.mp3" type="audio/mp3">

    </head>
<body>
    <div align="center" id="text">
    <h1>First Webpage</h1>
    <p>HTML</p>
    <p>+</p>
    <p>CSS</p>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well from hours of struggling you helped me xD thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Audio tag was on top of the text I guess, replace with this:

```
<audio autoplay loop> 
    <source src="seffelinie.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
</audio>
```

Comment: Yup that's what i first used, then I did some research and I changed it to relevant but still same result

Comment: And when I used center it just displayed the gif twice on the screen idk why

Comment: This might be easier, just create a div and use the background for it, give it a try https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size2

Comment: Ive used w3schools mostly to learn HTML and CSS but I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Found your problem, Audio was not closed, repleace with this:     <audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="seffelinie.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>

Comment: It's not just that the <`audio`> isn't closed, the `<head>` should close before the <`audio`> and be inside the `<body>` tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little mixed up. As stated above, you're missing the closing audio tag, but you are also closing the `<head>` after the audio element which should be inside the `<body>` tags with the rest of your html code. Lastly, I cleaned up your background image CSS to use best practices based on what I think you're intending. `background-position: relative;` isn't an option. `background-position` is not the same as `position`, it is for telling the browser what aspects of the parent to position the image based on — [like "top center" or "bottom left"](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-position.asp). In your case since you want the image to always cover, I think you're best off centering the image vertically and horizontally in all situations, that's what `background-position:` center center` does.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i91751/icons8/windows-8/Systems-Linux.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title>FirstWebpage</title>

    <style>
    body{ /* Will use a gif as background */
        background-image: url('http://images.eurogamer.net/2015/articles/1/8/7/1/5/3/2/san-francisco-subway-system-hacked-passengers-get-free-rides-148033947612.gif');
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="seffelinie.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <div align="center" id="text">
    <h1>First Webpage</h1>
    <p>HTML</p>
    <p>+</p>
    <p>CSS</p>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```